# C# Resetting rowid in sqlite database after deleting a row

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows

When i delete a row in sqlite DB(For exmaple:3rd row),the 4th row should be changed to 3rd,5th row to 4th and so on. How to do this in c#?

Comment: You need to execute an update like `UPDATE table SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > 4` but I would caution you against this. It is going to create massive maintenance problems and big sources of bugs and problems if you go down this path. Why do you care if the numbers are sequential or not?

Comment: The numbers has to be sequential because while retrieving,i count the number of rows in the database to dynamically create text boxes. After deleting a row in between,the contents at the end of database will not be shown